# how remove the first 37 columns in a test line using DOS command

Tags: cmd

I have this test file:
19/06/2022  11:05            38.841 2022.07.18-22.07.CPUUsage.txt

I w'd like get in my test file (with dos commands) ONLY:
2022.07.18-22.07.CPUUsage.txt
Thanks very much !

Comment: Your title says 37 characters but your example shows removing 24...

Comment: DOS file names are 8 characters only (plus a 3-character extension), so I assume it's `cmd` (the Windows Command Line) instead of the ancient console-based `dos`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the contents of the file into a variable using `for /f`. Then use substring variable expansion to get the bit you want. But inside a for loop you need delayed expansion turned on because accessing variables with `%` is done at the start of the for loop and not during each iteration - but that means you need to use `!` instead of `%` to access the variable.

Something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (data.txt) DO (
    set substring=%%i
    echo !substring:~24!
)
```

Double `%%` are needed if the commands are running inside a batch file.  Use single `%` if you are running it interactively.